# ansible: recursive loop detected in template string

Tags: ansible

In a playbook, I am using a role this way:

```
- { role: project, project_name: "{{project_name}}" }
```

And in the "project" role, I actually have a dependency that wants to use the project_name variable of the "project" role:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { 
      role: users, 
      users: [
        { 
            name: "{{project_name}}", 
            home: "/home/{{project_name}}",
            shell: "/bin/bash",
            group: "{{project_name}}",
        }
     ]
   }
```

But I get an error:

```
recursive loop detected in template string: {{project_name}}
```

Is changing the name of the "project_name" variable the only solution?

Thanks

Comment: I just encountered the same problem. I expected it to work in the same way that nested function calls work, but apparently it does not.

Answer (score 10):

External variables are inherited into roles automatically, so `project_name: "{{ project_name }}"` isn't necessary. Change your role declaration to:

```
- project
```

... and the `{{ project_name }}` variable will be available within your role as-is.

Comment: All right, thanks that works. I just wanted to be explicit when I was "calling" my role, I guess I cannot.

Comment: I found the following documentation helpful in determining Ansible variable precedence and inheritance rules :http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

Comment: Additional note: I ended up moving the conflicting vars from `vars/main.yml` to `default/main.yml` and it solved my issue.